# Access 2010 VBA: What is the VBA object that represents a Pivot Table Form field's returned values?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access-2010, pivot-table

I'm attempting to assign the result of an Access Pivot Table's field of queried values to an array variable, but I'm having trouble finding the appropriate representative object in the MSDN library for a Form/Pivot Table/field/ values.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

pivot tables are not supported in access 2013.

Can you get the same data from a recordset?

H

Comment: Interesting - didn't realize that about 2013.  I was able to get the full list of values from a recordset via the pivot table form object, but currently still stuck on how to narrow the values, respective of the current state of the pivot table filters.  Thanks for the attention, and the response!  & of course I welcome any further insight.

Comment: can you get the pivot table filters and use them to create a SQL statement used by the recordset?

Comment: Running into the same issue for the filters - I can get the filters' source values from the pivot tbl, but I can't seem to find a representative library object for a pivot table form's currently selected filter values.

Comment: Form.acFormPivotChart_Filter.Values = Form.txt1

See here: http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.access.modulesdaovba/vba-to-programmatically/47269

Comment: Thanks again, H.  I've decided to take the solution a different direction(I already have the same solution built in Excel, so going to retain it & connect it to the db).  Notably, I looked into your link but the author's code notes indicate the "Form.acFormPivotChart_Filter.Values" is a "pretend variable" (absent of what we're both searching for, no doubt).I couldn't find it nor similar so I assume that's why.  Also noteworthy- I did find my values buried deep in the form object properties via the locals window; however when I tried to reference them the object didn't support the reference.